# Proper way to create image field in a content entity

Tags: 8

My site allows users to upload images and add title and description to it. So I make a new class which extends `ContentEntityBase`. In its `baseFieldDefinitions()` method, I put an image field beside title and description fields:

```
$fields['image'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('image')
  ->setLabel(t('Image'))
  ->setRequired(TRUE);
```

I expect to see a file/image upload control in the add/edit form, but I don't see it. I see only the title and description textboxes.

I tried to find "*create('image')*" in all Drupal source code but didn't see any examples. So I don't know if creating an image field like this is the proper way or not?

Answer (score 10):

See ...

```
$entity->getFieldDefinition('image')

'file_extensions' => string(16) "png gif jpg jpeg"
'file_directory' => string(31) "[date:custom:Y]-[date:custom:m]"
```

And edit

```
$fields['image'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('image')
  ->setLabel(t('Image'))
  ->setDescription(t('Image field'))
  ->setSettings([
    'file_directory' => 'IMAGE_FOLDER',
    'alt_field_required' => FALSE,
    'file_extensions' => 'png jpg jpeg',
  ])
 ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'type' => 'default',
    'weight' => 0,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'type' => 'image_image',
    'weight' => 0,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Comment: All supported settings can be found in [ImageItem::defaultFieldSettings()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!image!src!Plugin!Field!FieldType!ImageItem.php/function/ImageItem%3A%3AdefaultFieldSettings/8.2.x) which also includes [FileItem::defaultFieldSettings()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!src!Plugin!Field!FieldType!FileItem.php/function/FileItem%3A%3AdefaultFieldSettings/8.2.x).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Matt for your prompt answer. I don't want to build the entity form and the image widget manually. Found out that I need to call `setDisplayOptions()` and `setDisplayOptions()` in `baseFieldDefinitions()`, now it works:

```
$fields['image'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('image')
  ->setLabel(t('Image'))
  ->setRequired(TRUE)
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label'   => 'above',
    'type'    => 'image',
    'weight'  => 0,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type'    => 'image_image',
    'weight'  => 0,
  ]);
```

Answer (score -3):

To create an image field you would use the form api like so:

```
$fields['image'] = array(
'#title' => t('Image'),
'#type' => 'managed_file',
'#description' => t('The uploaded image will be displayed on the node page.'),
'#default_value' => $this->get('image'),
'#upload_location' => 'public://images/',
'#required' => TRUE,
);
```

You can learn more here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements